# How to enable https for azure vm in Ubuntu server?

Tags: networking, server, nginx, azure

I have created a Virtual machine with Ubuntu server 22.04 LTS and have installed nginx in it. I am able to access VM through http using the public ip. But unable to access through https.

Should I configure inbound rules in Azure or anything to do in Ubuntu server?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Unfortunately there is not enough info here to say for certain what is missing from your configuration. Check first that the firewall rules in your Azure configurations allows for traffic over 443, then confirm that you have configured nginx to listen on both 80 and 443. One of those two items is *probably* the culprit.

Comment: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html has all you need

Comment: Hi, your question's title is about "how to" but the content is about "should I"... can you clear the actual question please?